# Webstorm highlight files with warnings

Tags: webstorm

While WebStorm correctly highlights all my files containing errors with red underwave, I was not able to find out how to similarly highlight files containing warnings.

I would appreciate something like orange underscore. Is it possible to achieve? How?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEA-96288](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96288)